# Eclipse - Error: <wicket:panel> is not recognized

Tags: java, html, eclipse, wicket

In my eclipse html Editor, I see these errors `- Error: <wicket:panel> is not recognized!`
I have included in the html tag the following but it is not still helping

```
    <html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use pretty much the same tag but with the xmlns added.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/dtds.data/wicket-xhtml1.4-strict.dtd">
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I found that it was a crushed installation of **Amateras HTML Editor** that was cuasing the problem. Following the guide at http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/docs/FacesIDE/InstallingAndUninstalling.html, I remove it and re-install it back. Now everything is okay. The xmln attribute is also important, if the file is opend with **Amateras**, hence accepting drobson's answer

Answer (score 2):

To use the latest xsd try the following snippet

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:wicket="https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/wicket/repo?p=wicket.git;a=blob_plain;f=wicket-core/src/main/resources/META-INF/wicket-1.5.xsd;hb=master">
```